Checkbox Selecteion in Recylerview Android Kotlin
Functionality Description:
Switch in Activity:
When the switch is turned on, all checkboxes within the RecyclerView should be checked (set to true).
When the switch is turned off, all checkboxes within the RecyclerView should be unchecked (set to false).
Manual Checkbox Handling:
Users can manually check and uncheck individual checkboxes.
If all checkboxes are manually checked, the switch should automatically turn on.
If any checkbox is manually unchecked while the switch is on, the switch should automatically turn off.
class BhkItemCheckboxAdapter(
private val context: Context,
private var items: List<BHK>,
private val onRadioButtonClick: OnCheckButtonClick

) : RecyclerView.Adapter<BhkItemCheckboxAdapter.ItemViewHolder>() {
var isAllChecked = false
inner class ItemViewHolder(view: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view) {
    val headTextView: TextView = view.findViewById(R.id.headTextView)
    val llRoot: LinearLayout = view.findViewById(R.id.llRoot)
    val cbType: CheckBox = view.findViewById(R.id.cbType)

    init {
        cbType.setOnCheckedChangeListener { _, isChecked ->
            if (isChecked) {
                llRoot.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.black_background)
                headTextView.setTextColor(context.getColor(R.color.search_field_child_text_white))
            } else {
                llRoot.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.gray_background)
                headTextView.setTextColor(context.getColor(R.color.search_field_child_text_black))
            }
            items[adapterPosition].checked = isChecked
            checkAllChecked()
        }
    }
}

override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ItemViewHolder {
    val view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
        .inflate(R.layout.item_child_checkbox, parent, false)
    return ItemViewHolder(view)
}

override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ItemViewHolder, position: Int) {
    val item = items[position]
    holder.headTextView.text = item.value
    holder.cbType.isChecked = item.checked

    if (item.checked){
        holder.llRoot.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.black_background)
        holder.headTextView.setTextColor(context.getColor(R.color.search_field_child_text_white))
    }
    else{
        holder.llRoot.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.gray_background)
        holder.headTextView.setTextColor(context.getColor(R.color.search_field_child_text_black))
    }


    holder.itemView.setOnClickListener {
        holder.cbType.isChecked = !holder.cbType.isChecked
        items[position].checked = holder.cbType.isChecked
        onRadioButtonClick.onClick(items[position].id)
        checkAllChecked()
    }
}

override fun getItemCount(): Int {
    return items.size
}

fun updateItems(checked: Boolean) {
    isAllChecked = checked
    for (item in items) {
        item.checked = checked
    }
    notifyDataSetChanged()
    onRadioButtonClick?.onAllChecked(checked)
}

private fun checkAllChecked() {
    for (item in items) {
        if (!item.checked) {
            isAllChecked = false
            onRadioButtonClick?.onAllChecked(false)
            return
        }
    }
    isAllChecked = true
    onRadioButtonClick?.onAllChecked(true)
}

}
Activity Code
  private fun setBedrooms(bhk: List<BHK>) {
    if (bhk != null) {
        llProperty.visibility = View.VISIBLE
        bhkList = bhk;
        lvBhkType = findViewById(R.id.lvBhkType)

        lvBhkType.layoutManager =
            GridLayoutManager(this, 3)

        val itemClickListener = object : OnCheckButtonClick {
            override fun onClick(id: String?, value: String?) {

                if (id != null) {
                    bhkId += "$id,"

                }
            }

            override fun onAllChecked(checked: Boolean) {
                rbBHKAll.isChecked = checked
            }

        }

        bhkAdapter = BhkItemCheckboxAdapter(this, bhk, itemClickListener)
        lvBhkType.adapter = bhkAdapter
    }
}
rbBHKAll.setOnCheckedChangeListener { _, isChecked ->
        bhkId = if (isChecked) {
            bhkList.joinToString(",") { it.id.toString() }
        } else {
            ""
        }
        bhkAdapter?.updateItems(isChecked)
    }


Can you be more specific about the issue or unwanted behavior you're experiencing with your current code?

I am facing an issue where, if all checkboxes are selected and I deselect one of them, all the other checkboxes get unchecked. Instead, only the selected checkbox should be unchecked while the others remain checked, and the switch in activity should turn off.

Remove checkAllChecked from onCheckedChangeListener and change activity one to onclick listener. Majority of mess comes from the fact that checked changed listener will trigger when you change checkbox state programatically.

I tried but Problem is not solved.
